# Length for drop down box in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Am still new to PHP and I would love to get help on setting the length for this language switcher (drop down box) left align in PHP.

Below is the code in my theme's header.php?:

```
   <?php
    if(function_exists("transposh_widget")) { 
        transposh_widget();
    }
    $top_bar_info = consulting_get_top_bar_info();
    ?>
```

In that same way, I need the PHP code to insert a search box next to it.

[image of my topbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi3qi.jpg)
I will be glad to get help from you